# how can i merge two videos with one mp3 with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I hope you can help me with on this.

I have a code in Php where I need to merged two MP4 videos and one MP3. Right now my code replace the Audio of the video with mp3 like this example:

```
ffmpeg -i "videoFile.mp4" -i "audioFile.mp3" -shortest outPutFile.mp4
```

I have found the way to merge the two mp4 files and removing the audio using this code:

```
ffmpeg -i videofile1.mp4 -i videofile2.mp4  -filter_complex "[0:v:0][1:v:0]concat=n=2:v=1[outv]" -map "[outv]"  output.mp4
```

What I would like to do is to merge this two mp4 files in one single command with the mp3 file cause I am using a php script to achieve this, so it takes some time to render the output and I don't want to send a Sleep command in PHP to wait to finish the conversion cause I will use this in cycle in the php script.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the audio file as another input and refer to it using `-map`:

```
ffmpeg -i videofile1.mp4 -i videofile2.mp4 -i audioFile.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v:0][1:v:0]concat=n=2:v=1[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 2:a -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: So much thank you, it works for me, I just missed the -map 2:a, the shortest I have it in my script.